# Create a new dataframe from an old dataframe where the new dataframe contains row-wise avergae of columns at different locations in the old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, mean

I have a dataframe called "frame" with 16 columns and 201 rows. A screenshot is attached that provides an example dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEFnU.png)

Please note the screenshot is just an example, the original dataframe is much larger.

I would like to find an efficient way (maybe using for loop or writing a function) to row-wise average different columns in the dataframe. For instance, to find an average of column **"rep" and "rep1"** and column **"repcycle" and "repcycle1" (similarly for set and setcycle)** and save in a new dataframe with only averaged columns.

I have tried writing a code using iloc

```
newdf= frame[['sample']].copy()
newdf['rep_avg']=frame.iloc[:, [1,5]].mean(axis=1)  #average row-wise
newdf['repcycle_avg']=frame.iloc[:, [2,6]].mean(axis=1)
newdf['set_avg']=frame.iloc[:, [3,7]].mean(axis=1)  #average row-wise  
newdf['setcycle_avg']=frame.iloc[:, [4,8]].mean(axis=1)
newdf.columns = ['S', 'Re', 'Rec', 'Se', 'Sec']
```

The above code does the job, but it is tedious to note the locations for every column. I would rather like to automate this process since this is repeated for other data files too.

Answer (score 0):

based on your desire "I would rather like to automate this process since this is repeated for other data files too"
what I can think of is this below:

```
in [1]:  frame = pd.read_csv('your path')
```

result shown below, now as you can see what you want to average are columns 1,5 and 2,6 and so on.

```
out [1]:
    sample  rep   repcycle  set   setcycle  rep1    repcycle1   set1    setcycle1
0   66      40    4         5     3         40      4           5       3
1   78      20    5         6     3         20      5           6       3
2   90      50    6         9     4         50      6           9       4
3   45      70    7         3     2         70      7           7       2
```

so, we need to create 2 lists

```
in [2]: import numpy as np
        list_1 = np.arange(1,5,1).tolist()
in [3]: list_1
out[3]: [1,2,3,4]
```

this for the first half you want to average[rep,repcycle,set,setcycle]

```
in [4]: list_2 = [x+4 for x in list_1]
in [5]: list_2
out[5]: [5,6,7,8]
```

this for the second half you want to average[rep1,repcycle1,set1,setcycle1]

```
in [6]: result = pd.concat([frame.iloc[:, [x,y].mean(axis=1) for x, y in zip(list_1,list_2)],axis=1)
in [7]: result.columns = ['Re', 'Rec', 'Se', 'Sec']
```

and now you get what you want, and it's automate, all you need to do is change the two lists from above.

```
in [8]: result
out[8]:
    Re    Rec   Se   Sec
0   40.0  4.0   5.0  3.0
1   20.0  5.0   6.0  3.0
2   50.0  6.0   9.0  4.0
3   70.0  7.0   5.0  2.0
```